# .NET Console Application to Web Service

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, web-services

I have a console application in VS2010 which uses a third party ActiveX dll. It all works fine. But I want to implement the same code as a web service.

I tried creating a WCF service and then copying all the code into the new project. But I get an error while invoking any function on the dll. Although I am running it under x86 platform, it gives me 'Bad Format Exception'.

Is there any way where I can directly host my console application as a service?

Comment: Is your application pool in IIS running 32 bit mode?

Comment: My application is running in 32bit mode.

Comment: Not sure what is application pool in ISS

Comment: if you are running your wcf in IIS you can set the app pool to run in 64 bit and 32 bit mode.

Comment: Victor, I want to make it a Restful web service. I will be running it as a Windows Service. I have created a dummy Restful service which works fine. But it gives exceptions when I add the dll. So I am thinking to do a work around. I want to host the same console application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is called "self-hosting". From "[Fundamental Windows Communication Foundation Concepts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731079.aspx)":

> **self-hosted service**
>      A service that runs within a process application that the developer created. The developer controls its lifetime, sets the properties of the service, opens the service (which sets it into a listening mode), and closes the service.

Comment: Thank you so much guys... Its working fine now... I used self hosting... :D